# Navigate through vim's preview window

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I am working on a Python project using Vim with YouCompleteMe code completion. The thing is most of the docstrings don't fit in the preview window. Is it possible to increase the preview window height or navigate through it?

Comment: `:help preview-window`.

Comment: @romainl thanks! `previewheight` was the option I was looking for!

Comment: Can any of you add correct comment as an answer ?

Comment: Is it possible to scroll the window while it's open, in insert mode, without dismissing it?

Comment: @BallpointBen Seems you need a plugin for that functionality.  See [vim-preview](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-preview-care-of-itself) which introduces the command `:PreviewScroll` that you can keymap to insert mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the info you need on the preview window in:

```
:help preview-window
```

Take a look at the `previewheight` option:

```
:help 'previewheight'
```